# Problema UTF-8 y iso-8859-1

Tags: html

Me han pasado una página web que poseía el siguiente código en el head:

```
<head>
<!--COMIENZO: CABECERA USUARIO-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<!--FIN: CABECERA USUARIO-->
<!--METAINFORMACION DE LA PAGINA-->
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
```

Pero en el servidor no funciona, ¿podría ser problema de Apache? Debido a que he probado a utilizar el siguiente código:

```
<head>
<!--COMIENZO: CABECERA USUARIO-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<!--FIN: CABECERA USUARIO-->
<!--METAINFORMACION DE LA PAGINA-->
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
```

Comment: Que es lo que no funciona? Has guardado el archivo con la codificación correspondiente?

Comment: En el servidor estaba con el 1º código y ahora les aparece que las tildes y demás caracteres con el símbolo de interrogación. Pero he probado con el 2º código y me sigue apareciendo el mismo error. ¿Puede ser que el servidor tenga en Apache un utf definido?

Comment: En efecto, puede ser el charset de apache o de php si estás presentando el html usando PHP. En el caso de apache lo puedes cambiar en httpd.conf o desde la cuenta cPanel si es un hosting compartido.

Answer (score 1):

El codigo html esta bien y deberia tomar las tildes, las ñ y otros caracteres.
Segun mi experiencia estas cosas fallan cuando estas tratando de traer textos desde el codigo fuente por ejemplo una pagina en utf-8 y le pone texto en iso-8859-1

Si utilizas php por ejemplo. la transformacion de un charset puede ocasionar problemas por un distinto formato en la base de datos

```
<?PHP 
   $contenido = “ÑñÑñ papá”
   echo iconv(mb_detect_encoding($contenido, mb_detect_order(), true),   "UTF-8", $contenido);
```

Esto corrige errores  charset y fuerza a que sea en utf-8

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero después de darme mucho mal ayer, hable con los encargados del servidor y resulto ser que el Apache tenía un utf definido.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías cambiar el formato del archivo html o php. Cuando tu lo tenías en el antiguo formato al, UTF-8 tu codificación de archivo seguirá siendo la misma. Si estas en submime o a note pad ve a Archivo > Codificacion > UTF-8